# Projection operator (relative angular momentum) in FQHE Toy hamiltonian

Tags: operators, wavefunction, hamiltonian, quantum-hall-effect

I am working on Fractional Quantum Hall Effect and reading these lecture notes http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qhe/qhe.pdf. As all others sources I have found, none of them precisely define the projecto operator $ P_{m'}(ij)$ mentioned here on p84 or give a mathematical argument on why is thus $V_m \Phi = 0 $ (so why are the Laughlin states ground state of the toy hamiltonian).

The best 'attempt' or beginning of a explicit proof I have found is on the p11 of the following :
http://www.phys.virginia.edu/Files/fetch.asp?EXT=Seminars:1752:SlideShow

But I am still a bit confused on how to get the explicit expression for $\phi_c^{rel}$, or said otherwise how to go from line 2 to 3 ?

\begin{equation}
    H =  \sum_{m'=1}^{\inf} \sum_{i<j} v_{m'}P_{m'}(ij)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \phi(z_i) =  \prod_{i<j}(z_i-z_j)^m e^{-\sum _i \mid z_i \mid ^2 / 4l^2_B} 
\end{equation}
So ho do we move from here to a decomposition in relative angular momentum ? 
\begin{equation}
    \phi(z_i) =  \sum_a \sum_{b,c} C_a^{b,c} \phi_b^{CM}(\frac{1}{2}(z_1+z_2)) \phi_c^{rel} (z_1-z_2)  e^{-\sum _i \mid z_i \mid ^2 / 4l^2_B} \Phi(z_2,z_3, ...,z_N)
\end{equation}

Comment: If you haven't already, you might want to try to read Haldane's chapter in Prange and Girvin's book on the QHE. I think that might be helpful. I might try to write up an answer later.

Comment: Thank you ! I did already read the Prange and Girvin's chapter you recommended. They indeed use and define these projection operators but don't give and explicit expression or how do they act on the wave function.

I am finding something that could work but would need to work why the projection operator doesn't 'see' the center of mass termes (z_i+z_j) which I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still interested in the answer, but I think I found something.
Since we're working in two dimensions (i.e. x-y plane), angular momentum is defined as $$J = i\hbar\, (x\frac{\partial}{\partial y} - y\frac{\partial}{\partial x}).$$
This transformed in $z = x-iy,\,\overline{z}=x+iy$, coordinates reads (fairly easy to check) $$J = \hbar\, (z\,\frac{\partial}{\partial z}-\overline{z}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial{\overline{z}}}).$$
From here, it means that relative angular momentum operator reads (neglecting $\hbar$) $$J_{ij} = (z_i-z_j)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial (z_i-z_j)}-(\overline{z}_i - \overline{z}_j)\,\frac{\partial}{\partial{(\overline{z}_i - \overline{z}_j)}}.$$
Now, projection operators are projecting on eigenstates of $J_{ij}$ with eigenvalue $m'$ which are $\phi_{m'}^{ij} = (z_i-z_j)^{m'} e^{-|z_i-z_j|^2/4}$. This isn't hard to check (remember that $|z|^2 = z\cdot \overline{z}$).

I still have to figure out how to show that Laughlin state is then ground state of Toy Hamiltonian composed of these projection operators, but as soon as I do I will post it.